# Extracting columns from a string or list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract columns from a string of values in python. The string of values looks like follows -

```
CN=Unix ADISID,OU=SA,OU=DGO,DC=dom,DC=ab,DC=com,1001
CN=1002--DS,OU=Process,DC=dom,DC=ab,DC=com,1002
CN=1003--Cyb,OU=SA,OU=DGO,DC=dom,DC=ab,DC=com,1003
CN=Doe--Joe,OU=Adm,DC=dom,DC=ab,DC=com,d1004
CN=cruise--bob,OU=SA,OU=DGO,DC=dom,DC=ab,DC=com,d1005
```

Now I would like to extract columns from this string with column headers like CN, OU1, OU2,DC1, DC2, DC3,ID. The number of OU and DC values are different in every line so if they are not present in a line, I would like to keep that column as blank. Also, I'm using the following piece of code to generate the above string.

```
result = l.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes)

results=""
for i in [entry for dn, entry in result if isinstance(entry, dict)]:
    results += str(i.get('distinguishedName')[0] +","+ i.get('sAMAccountName')[0] + "\n").replace("\, ","--")        
print results
```

Will it be easier if I create results as a list to begin with?

Comment: What is your expected output? Your question doesn't seem sufficiently clear.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ apologies if the question is not clear to you. I would like to extract the column headers and corresponding values from every line in my string. e.g. from the first like CN, 2 OUs(OU1, OU2, OU3, OU4), 3 DC (DC1- DC4), and the last field ID. As OU3, OU4 & DC4 donot hav value in row1 their value should be blank. Hope this makes sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "fields left blank" behavior, you're going to have to count the max number of each field. I believe that CN is unique, so that should always be 1.

```
result = l.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes)

users = []

for i in [entry for dn, entry in result if isinstance(entry, dict)]:
    dn = i.get('distinguishedName')[0].replace('\, ', '--').split(',')
    info = collections.defaultdict(list)
    info['id'] = i.get('sAMAccountName')[0]

    for part in dn:
        key,value = part.split('=',1)
        info[key].append(value)

    users.append(info)

max_cn = max(map(lambda u: len(u['CN']), users))
assert max_cn == 1

max_ou = max(map(lambda u: len(u['OU']), users))
max_dn = max(map(lambda u: len(u['DN']), users))

numflds = max_cn + max_ou + max_dn

fields = []
for u in users:
    f = [u['CN']]
    ou = u['OU'] + [''] * max_ou
    f.extend(ou[:max_ou])
    dn = u['DN'] + [''] * max_dn
    f.extend(dn[:max_dn])
    f.append(u['id'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried to run the code provided by you. But getting an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'` on line `part.split('=',1)`. I understand what the error is but do not understand what you are trying to do. Could you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: My bad. I think it was creating a nested iterable. I patched the code.

Comment: if I print f at the end, I just get the last record. Could you please let me know what is the missing bit ?

Comment: That's up to you. Either print f inside the loop, or append it to fields, or something. But f gets reset each pass through, so you'll have to do it inside the loop.

Comment: Works like a charm!. Thank you! I do not have the reputation to vote your answer but would certainly give you +100 :-)

Answer (score 0):

For each line:

```
pairs = [kv.split('=') for kv in line.split(',')]
for pair in pairs:
    if len(pair) == 1:
        pair.insert(0, 'ID')
```

Now you have something like this:

```
[['CN', 'Unix ADISID'],
 ['OU', 'SA'],
 ['OU', 'DGO'],
 ['DC', 'dom'],
 ['DC', 'ab'],
 ['DC', 'com'],
 ['ID', '1001']]
```

Then:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mapping = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in pairs:
    mapping[k].append(v)
```

Which gives you:

```
{'CN': ['Unix ADISID'],
 'DC': ['dom', 'ab', 'com'],
 'ID': ['1001'],
 'OU': ['SA', 'DGO']}
```